# How to copy all column names and data types from table in DBeaver?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

So I have this table with a LOT of columns. And I am trying to do pxf connection from another database where this table is. Are there any way I can copy or export maybe all
column name - data type pairs, so I won't have to announce it one by one in while creating external table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could generate the DDL from that table and use it as you need, by clicking right mouse button and selecting from menu Generate SQL-->DDL.